# Joining more than one common table expression (CTE) is taking too long in SQL (query will not end) is there something wrong with my code?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, query-performance

I am running a query with two CTEs that join and then a query that uses the joined CTEs. However this query was running for several hours yesterday and never completed. Queries where I am usually complete within the minute.

This is the query I am runnning:

```
WITH cte_second_try AS (
SELECT primary_key as timing,
MIN(timedate) AS second_try,
FROM table t1
WHERE timedate > (SELECT MIN(timedate) FROM table t2 WHERE t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key group by primary_key)
AND criteria1='x' AND timedate BETWEEN 'x' AND 'x' GROUP BY 1),

cte_timing AS (
SELECT MIN(timedate) AS first_try, MIN(second_try) AS second_try,
FROM table t3
LEFT JOIN cte_second_try ON t3.primary_key = cte_second_try.timing
WHERE criteria1='x' AND timedate BETWEEN 'x' AND 'x' group by 1)

SELECT id, t4.primary_key, var2, var3, var4, var5 etc
 CASE
 WHEN var2 <> 'string'
 THEN 0
 WHEN cte_timing.first_try = t4.timedate
 THEN 1
 WHEN cte_timing.second_try = t4.timedate
 THEN 2
 ELSE 3 END
FROM table t4
 LEFT JOIN cte_timing ON t4.primary_key = cte_timing.primary_key
WHERE criteria1='x' AND timedate BETWEEN 'x' AND 'x'
ORDER BY timedate;
```

Any suggestions as to what is causing this bottleneck?

Furthermore this is my first time joining CTEs so there might be something wrong in how I have joined the CTEs. The general idea is that I find the second attempt at a task in the first CTE and the first attempt at a task in the second CTE and then reference both via the second in the query at the end.

I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: Could you join the explain plan?

Comment: My guess would be in `cte_second_try`. When you run just `select count(*) from cte_second_try`, would it finish?

Comment: I dont see how that would help the rest of the query would be broken

Comment: Can you explain what is meant by this line?  WHERE timedate > (SELECT MIN(timedate) FROM table t2 WHERE t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key group by primary_key)
If primary key is really the PK then wouldn't this always mean zero results?

Comment: Check the explain plan for each query.  Break your query up into parts and start with the smallest possible part, then add pieces to it one by one and you will find the issue.

Comment: It is cte_second_try that is the issue, it will not complete. Not quite sure why yet though

Comment: I am trying to find the second lowest by removing the MIN(timedate) first

Comment: and the primary keys are all from the same tables so that part seems ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the answer to this question.

I have just heard back from a tech guy and it is because of indexing.

By adding an index the cost of the query went from:

cost=151491121951.08
to
cost=820386.91

You can do:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT primary_key as timing,
MIN(timedate) AS second_try,
FROM table t1
WHERE timedate > (SELECT MIN(timedate) FROM table t2 WHERE t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key group by primary_key)
AND criteria1='x' AND timedate BETWEEN 'x' AND 'x' GROUP BY 1
```

to get the cost of the query using `EXPLAIN`